# C# BeginReceive for UDP

Tags: c#, .net, udp, udpclient

I'm trying to learn how to use BeginReceive for UDP, here's what I have:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing SNMP Listener on Port:" + port + "...");
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(port);
        //UdpState state = new UdpState(client, remoteSender);


        try
        {
          client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }


    }

    private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        int port = 162;
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(port);
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162);
        byte[] received = client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received));
        client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);

    }
```

Nothing happens, the code just end's without even calling the recv method. Why is that ?

**Edit**:

Added :-

```
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Now it's giving me an exception at the below line:

```
 Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted.
```

**TRIED :-**

```
       try
        {
          client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), client);
        }

    private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
    //    int port = 162;

        try
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162);
            byte[] received = res.AsyncState.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received));
            res.AsyncState.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }
```

**Error:**

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'EndReceive' and no extension method 'EndReceive' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Did you breakpoint it before posting this question? See what happens? See where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first part of your code is essentially the body of your main function you shouldn't be surprised that it ends. Put a

```
Console.Readline();
```

before the closing `}` of `main` to wait.

`recv` will be called asynchronously as soon as some data arrived. Then you need to read the received data from the very UDP client that was waiting. In order to access this client you'll hand it over via the state parameter of `BeginReceive`

```
client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), client);
```

and finally get it from the callbacks IAsyncResult parameter

```
UdpClient client = (UdpClient)res.AsyncState;
```

It may be easier (but less flexible) to store the client in a class field.

Now you get your data from

```
byte[] received = client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Comment: I did this it's giving me an exception at UdpClient client = new UdpClient(port);

Comment: Then the port's probably in use. Choose another one. However, this is not related actually.

Comment: I'm opening the port in main, as a reference to call the beginreceive, then I do it again in recv, this isn't premitted.

Comment: Sure, you can't do that. And you need not to do it. Just put the `client` in main as the parameter to `BeginReceive` (instead of null). Then you extract the client in `recv` from res (it's in AsyncState).

Comment: I tried that please see my edit above, it's giving me an error for the object parameter being passes

Comment: it's working I used :  UdpClient c = (UdpClient)(res.AsyncState); in recv method. I got this from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132623/Basic-UDP-Receiver.

Comment: Can you please explain me what exactly does this mean: (UdpClient)(res.AsyncState);

Comment: Found an answer, it's casting of type object to type udpclient thanks for this. I'm accepting your answer but please reflect these changes to your answer. Thank you.